# How to use dynamic schema names in Entity class in Java when using Spring boot JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to connect to two databases servers oracle and sqlserver.
Oracle server has a user that has access to two schemas(say user, hr).

Similarly sqlserver has a user that connects a database which has tables under schema different from oracle.

**[Implementation]**

I have created the configuration to connect to both of them referring to below post and defined my entities.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources

However I am not able to figure out the best way to mention schemas on entity class as I don't want to hardcode the schema names in Table annotation because this will be changing for Production and lower environments.

**[Example]**

user.customer_table means when I query customer entity I need to use user.customer_table

hr.salary_table means when I query salary entity I need to use hr.salary_table.

What I Tried

- property binding by mentioning schema names in application.properties but it won't replace the schema attribute if I use placeholder.
- referred below post but did not have good luck either.

https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-set-the-schema-name-dynamically-in-spring-jpa-b0f1c2205ad2

**[Tech stack]**

- Spring boot 3, Hibernate 6

Answer (score 0):

So don't shoot me down if this is not a solution for you but here is something I did. In the event I have multiple databases and schemas in JPA I do this.

Actually Edit: i just looked at the link you shared and its the same pattern this might make it easier to follow.

I use a pattern in application.properties to identify a data source by a name kind of like this where the source name is trade. I can specify sql server oracle or whatever.

**spring.trade.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jkj?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.trade.datasource.username=root
spring.trade.datasource.password=3goldPijkjgs1!
spring.trade.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.trade.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.trade.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10000**

Next I create a Configuration class for each data source or data base and I specify the package of the JPA entities, configure the EntityManger and EntityManagerFactory that is needed to autowire in entity repository clases.
Before you need these annotations tells what package entities are for this db

```
  @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "tradeEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "tradeTransactionManager", basePackages = {
        "com.dunkware.trade.service.beach.server.entity" })



public class TradeDBConfig {

@Value("${spring.trade.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
private String hbm2dllUpdate;

@Primary
@Bean(name = "tradeDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.trade.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource source = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    return source;
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "tradeEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("tradeDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    // Dangerous!
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2dllUpdate);
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).properties(properties)
            .packages("com.dunkware.trade.service.beach.server.entity").persistenceUnit("trade").build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "tradeTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager tradeTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("tradeEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory tradeEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(tradeEntityManagerFactory);
}
```

There is one more trick you have to do, when annotating entity objects they need to specify the name of the class as entity name in annotation like this.

@Entity(name = "BeachSystemEnt")

Good luck hope I at least gave you some context.

Comment: One other thing, you have to get the naming pattern right in that Config class like tradeEntityManager is named by having the data source name define in application.properties our case trade prefix these things. follow the pattern.

Comment: thank you Duncan , where are you setting the schema here.? 

**[oracle server]**
-myoracleuser.user_schema.customer_table,

-myoracleuser.hr_schema.salary_table,

**[sqlserver]**

-mysqlserveruser.mysqldatabase.dbo.my_table.

Comment: So I assume each schema oracle and sqlserver don't have the same tables and entities. The approach I showed seperates the tables or entities between the two data sources so you don't even need to worry about it. Just auto import a JPA Entity Repository, or create a JPA entity from one of your schemas and it inserts correctly into the right schema. Look in config class for each data source it points to the schema entity package. does that help ?

Comment: Don't think of setting users, or prefixing schemas, the solution will do that all for you using JPA. in your application properties like the example above you create two different data sources, one for Oracle and other for SQLServer, in those properties you specify the user, the schema for each and the password. In application code get the thought of what user or schema out of your mind, Just use JPA Entity Repositories, and Entities that map to tables in your schemas. You get the Entity object, create it and save it in the correct persistent context.

Comment: thanks Duncan , the datasource of oracle itself has two schemas and hence one datasource is not sufficient I presume. I wanted to avoid creating two datasource for oracle just because I have two schemas because I felt that is not an elegant solution. Ofcourse sqlserver needs another datasource but oracle in this case doesn't need two datasource but it just needs a way to point to specific schema in its entities which I can't hard code in schema property of @Table as they will change for dev / sit/ uat / prod environment.